# I can't understand why I'm not able to override a Bootstrap style with my own style sheet in this particular case

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple site using bootstrap and I was trying to modify the style of a alert box.

In the head I'm linking to the Bootstrap CSS, the Bootstrap optional theme, and then my custom style sheet (in this order). This is the alert box which I'm trying to customize:

```
<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">Success</div>
```

In my custom style sheet I have:

```
#success {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: red;
}
```

What happens is that the font color and the border color do change to white and red, respectively, but the background does not.

After spending a lot of time searching and trying different approaches I noticed that if I do not use the optional Bootstrap theme then the background color does change to the one I specify. However I don't fully understand why. I have been looking at the optional theme CSS which states for this alert box:

```
alert-success {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dff0d8), to(#c8e5bc));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdff0d8', endColorstr='#ffc8e5bc', GradientType=0);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #b2dba1;
}
```

I see that the color that insists on not changing to black (the green #dff0d8) is mentioned several times here. I think that the reason that I can't change the background color of the alert-success box when using the optional CSS theme is because when using this theme the background is no longer a "solid color" as in "background-color: black;" but becomes a webkit gradient (whatever that is). Am I understanding this correctly? Is there an easy way to override this or turn of this gradient for this particular alert box in my custom CSS sheet.

I'm new to this and I don't yet fully understand the webkit rules in CSS sheets. Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Thanks to the help of everyone below I was able to understand the problem and correct it. Here it is:

The optional bootstrap theme that I'm using creates the background through "background-image" and not "background-color" like I was trying to do. So even though I am correctly changing the background-color, a background-image is being created on top of it. There are to ways to do what I want here:
 - Adding "background-image: none;" in the custom CSS
 - Changing "background-color: black;" to "background: black;" in the custom CSS rule

Thanks everyone.

Comment: did you try `div#success.alert-success` in your CSS? the more specific the better

Comment: are you sure your CSS is loading? can you share more of your html? perhaps reproduce the issue into a jsfiddle? or bootply? Your code should work, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sn5jsskf/

Comment: CSS is loading for sure. I can change border color and font color. Just not background color. The answer from the other poster (Houdmont) helped me understand. I think in your fiddle you're not using the optional bootstrap theme (bootstrap-theme.css) like I am. The theme creates the background through "background-image" and not "background-color" like I was trying to do. So even though I am correctly changing the background-color, a background-image is being created on top of it. I am able to do what I wanted by adding "background-image: none;" in my css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the background-image property as well as setting the background colour.

```
#success {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Removing the background-image property worked! So I was understanding it correctly. I was correctly setting the background color but a background image was being set on top of it by the webkit on the optional bootstrap style sheet. Thanks a lot. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a messy solution using `!important`

```
#success {
color: white;
background-color: black !important;
border-color: red;
}
```

You could also try to be more specific in your selection:

```
div#success.alert-success {
color: white;
background-color: black !important;
border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Using !important was my first thought and it doesn't work here. I don't understand why. I just tried using div#success.alert-success as a selector and it didn't work.

Comment: there is no need to use `!important` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `background-color: black;` to `background: black;` in your custom CSS rule.

```css
#success {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border-color: red;
}
.alert-success {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dff0d8), to(#c8e5bc));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdff0d8', endColorstr='#ffc8e5bc', GradientType=0);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #b2dba1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">Success</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. This also works. I now have too working solutions and fully understood the problem. Thnaks a lot.